# Kotlin - Delegation chain

Tags: kotlin, delegates

In Kotlin, is it possible to have a Delegation chain ? 
To demonstrate what i'm trying to achieve here's the example (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) in the kotlin doc modified :

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { println(x) }
}

class Derived(var b: Base, val someData: Float = 10f) : Base by b

class SecondDerived(var b: Base) : Base by b

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = BaseImpl(10)
    val derived = Derived(b)
    val secondDerived: Base = SecondDerived(derived)
    secondDerived.print()// prints 10

    if (secondDerived is Derived) println(secondDerived.someData) //here secondDerived is Derived == false
}
```

I would expect "secondDerived" to be of type "Derived" but the cast say it is not.

I suspect that in memory the secondDerived base is indeed of type Derived, but the compiler cannot see that. Is there any way to make the cast work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the JVM, a class can have only a single superclass, and Kotlin's class delegation does not change it in any way. All it does is generate implementations of `Base` interface methods that delegate to the `Derived` instance. It does not affect `is` checks.